# The Javascript onclick event only fire on the second click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an `onclick` problem.  I searched the internet, but the people who had the same problem do not fully explain how they fixed the problem.  I cannot figure out what goes on here.

I am supposed to make a button called "Load New", when clicked it showed allow a user to select a file.

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" class="clear-button" onclick="clearB()" value="Clear Board" /><br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Load Game To Board" onclick="LoadGame()" />
<input type="button" id="get_file" onclick="n();" value="Load New Game">
<input type="file" id="my_file">
```

**CSS**

```
#my_file {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
function n() {
    if (document.getElementById('get_file') != null) {
        document.getElementById('get_file').onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById('my_file').click();
        }
        //LoadGame(); //triggers this function without allowing the user to open file.
    }
}
```

Lastly I cannot put a function to manipulate the contents of the file in the function n().  No matter where I put it, it triggers the function without opening the file-select dialog.

Comment: What do you mean by `put a function to manipulate the contents of the file `?

Answer (score 0):

The dialog is not visible after the first click because the first click attaches the event handler an anonymous function to open `my_file` but it does not execute it.

The second click executes the anonymous function since it is already attached. This fires the click event for `my_file`:

```
  function showFileUpload(){        
        document.getElementById('get_file').onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById('my_file').click()
        }
  }
```

This version fires the click event for `my_file`

```
 function showFileUpload_2(){
document.getElementById('my_file').click()                               
 }
```

This is the html

```
  <input type="button" id="get_file" 
          onclick="showFileUpload_2();" value="Load New Game">
    <input type="file" id="my_file">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for this function -

```
document.getElementById('get_file').onclick = function() { 
.....
}
```

Change your script as

```
<script>
    function n(){

if(document.getElementById('get_file') != null){
//document.getElementById('get_file').onclick = function() {  //comment this function
    document.getElementById('my_file').click()


//}

//LoadGame(); //triggers this function without allowing the user to open file.
}
}
</script>
```